# Angular entries - for type object

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using Angular. I need to iterate over an object to get the required values from an array. In this case, the "entries" method is not available. How to solve this problem?

```
      searchNode(items: { [key: string]: any }) {

        for (let [index, element] of items.entries()) {

          console.log(index)
          console.log(element)

        }

      }
```

[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/022Ux.png)

Comment: It's pretty simple just use Object.keys method:



Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
  console.log(key)
  console.log(item[key])
})

Comment: `.entries` is a method and not a property. so change to `... of items.entries() ) {...`

Comment: `for (let [index, element] of Object.entries(items))`